# Run command after webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'd like to run webpack in `--watch` mode, and run a shell command after each build that synchronizes a folder to another one.

I found [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/on-build-webpack) that triggers an event after each build. That works, but the last piece of the puzzle is to trigger a shell command (for syncing) from Javascript. Any pointers on how to achieve this are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily run any shell command with built-in [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) module. Also you can try some shell libraries for node.js, like [Shell.js](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs). It wraps most of default shell for more convenient usage

Comment: Thank you, that was the missing link. I somehow was going in circles and completely missed this option.

Comment: An example would be welcome for those who are merely users of webpack.

Answer (score 170):

## Webpack 4

As of today (April 11, 2018), most of the plugins I've tried use the deprecated API resulting in this warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
```

It pleased me to find that you can easily write an ad-hoc webpack plugin ([docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/)).

In your `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

module.exports = {

  // ... other config here ...

  plugins: [

    // ... other plugins here ...

    {
      apply: (compiler) => {
        compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', (compilation) => {
          exec('<path to your post-build script here>', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (stdout) process.stdout.write(stdout);
            if (stderr) process.stderr.write(stderr);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

If you'd rather use [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) to get real-time or "live" data from your script, this illustrates the basic usage:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const child = spawn('<your script here>');
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    process.stdout.write(data);
});
child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    process.stderr.write(data);
});
```

Comment: Great, also works on watch builds, what didn't seem to be the case with Yair Tavor's solution.

Comment: Just a heads up, if you're looking for the **before** equivalent of the hook, you can try `beforeCompile`. Documentation on which hooks are available can be found [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/)

Comment: Are you sure about "<path to your post-build script here>"? Docs says that it should be "the command to run": https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback .  When I have a path there it complaints about permission: "/bin/sh: tasks/postbuild.sh: Permission denied"

Comment: @Andrey you can supply a command to run, or a path to a script file with the execute permission set. To fix your problem try `chmod +x /path/to/script`

Comment: Yes, but if webpack has child compilations, it will not work

Answer (score 81):

I also needed such a thing, so I compiled a super simple plugin to execute shell commands before and after each build.

```
'use strict';

var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
}

function WebpackShellPlugin(options) {
  var defaultOptions = {
    onBuildStart: [],
    onBuildEnd: []
  };

  this.options = Object.assign(defaultOptions, options);
}

WebpackShellPlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
  const options = this.options;

  compiler.plugin("compilation", compilation => {
    if(options.onBuildStart.length){
        console.log("Executing pre-build scripts");
        options.onBuildStart.forEach(script => exec(script, puts));
    }
  });

  compiler.plugin("emit", (compilation, callback) => {
    if(options.onBuildEnd.length){
        console.log("Executing post-build scripts");
        options.onBuildEnd.forEach(script => exec(script, puts));
    }
    callback();
  });
};

module.exports = WebpackShellPlugin;
```

then in your webpack config:

```
plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPlugin({ 
         onBuildStart: ['echo "hello world"'], 
         onBuildEnd: ['echo "goodbye world"'] 
    })
]
```

This is super basic, and do not support async scripts properly. but it works. feel free to modify however you see fit.

> Consider this code under MIT licence.
>
> Needs node 4.x and up to run, as I use some es6 features here.

Comment: If you need to access the bundle files it's better to use `after-emit`, since `emit` is triggered when Webpack starts emitting the files.

Comment: can u create a non e6 verion?

Comment: It's been packaged at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin

Comment: I boiled this down to simply pass a single js function rather than a string command to `exec`.  Works well.

Answer (score 7):

Use [webpack-shell-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin)

**How to Use:**

```
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');


    module.exports = {
      ...
      ...
      plugins: [
        new WebpackShellPlugin({onBuildStart:['echo "Webpack Start"'], onBuildEnd:['echo "Webpack End"']})
      ],
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Note: this is actually a plugin suggested by @Yair Tavor in his anwser.

Comment: @Olga reducing the solution to what is strictly necessary is an actual contribution and deserves credit. 

Krishna you can enhance your answer by explaining the differences with Yair Tavor's answer. As far as I understand, Yair Tavor's solution has been packaged in the webpack-shell-plugin and what you propose is how to use it.
It is worthwhile mentionning to help others understand the situation.

Answer (score 7):

Basically, you can hook into the compiler at various stages of the whole compilation to emitting resources stage etc and run your own script or code as you please.

I like to do it this way -

```
class CustomPlugin {
  constructor(name, command, stage = 'afterEmit') {
    this.name = name;
    this.command = command;
    this.stage = stage;
  }

  static execHandler(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (stdout) process.stdout.write(stdout);
    if (stderr) process.stderr.write(stderr);
  }

  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks[this.stage].tap(this.name, () => {
      exec(this.command, CustomPlugin.execHandler);
    });
  }
}
```

and then use it like so

```
new CustomPlugin('RunTest', 'jest', 'beforeRun'),
```

Comment: I can see myself using this pattern a lot.

Answer (score 5):

## `webpack-shell-plugin-next` plugin

There is the `webpack-shell-plugin-next` plugin:

- GitHub: [s00d/webpack-shell-plugin-next: Run shell commands either before or after webpack 4 builds](https://github.com/s00d/webpack-shell-plugin-next).

  - Please, see the [«Webpack compatibility»](https://github.com/s00d/webpack-shell-plugin-next#webpack-compatibility) section.
- npm: [webpack-shell-plugin-next - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin-next).

### Using the plugin

The `onAfterDone` [plugin API](https://github.com/s00d/webpack-shell-plugin-next#api):

> `onAfterDone`: configuration object for scripts that execute after done.

may be used to achieve the desired watch-related behaviour (in addition, please, see the **important note** below):

> I'd like to run webpack in `--watch` mode, and run a shell command after each build that synchronizes a folder to another one.

**Important note**: the `onAfterDone` plugin API **will work for (affect) the normal build mode too** (i.e. the `webpack` command without the `--watch` option).

Here is an additional reference to the related GitHub issue: [onDoneWatch scripts executing before bundle written · Issue #16 · s00d/webpack-shell-plugin-next](https://github.com/s00d/webpack-shell-plugin-next/issues/16).

### Example

Have just tried to use the plugin: it has worked fine.

#### `devDependencies` (from `package.json`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  "webpack": "5.3.2",
  "webpack-cli": "4.1.0",
  "webpack-shell-plugin-next": "2.0.4"
}
```

#### `watch` npm run script (from `package.json`)

```
"scripts": {
  "watch": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch"
}
```

#### Webpack configuration file (`webpack.config.js`)

```
const WebpackShellPluginNext = require('webpack-shell-plugin-next');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new WebpackShellPluginNext({
            onAfterDone: {
                scripts: ['echo "It works!"'],
                blocking: true,
                parallel: false
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

#### Command line to run Webpack in the watch mode

```
npm run watch
```

Comment: works really great with webpack 4 also. Just remember to use for webpack 4 different version:
webpack4 => "webpack-shell-plugin-next": "1.2.0"
webpack5 => "webpack-shell-plugin-next": "2.2.2"

Answer (score 2):

If you guya want to do it when a specific file gets changed you can use this little plugin I built: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-noodle-plugin

Hope it can help

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with `webpack-shell-plugin` and `webpack-shell-plugin-next`: the scripts were executing **before** the new files were emitted, even though I was using `onDoneWatch`.

That's when I found [hook-shell-script-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hook-shell-script-webpack-plugin).
Works like a charm.

Comment: There are already plenty of answers solving the problem, please add some additional information how your answer differs.

Comment: The other answers point to `webpack-shell-plugin` or to custom implementations using webpack hooks. I couldn't get the shell plugin to work, and making a custom plugin seems way overkill. I found this other solution no one else pointed out. Hope it might help