# Webpack Plugin: run command after assets are written to file system

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

I've seen this question: [Run command after webpack build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312715/run-command-after-webpack-build) and I modified the sample code provided there.

To describe my scenario, I'm trying to take the assets output by webpack and deploy them to a mounted network drive. I'm using `ncp` to copy a directory and the actual copy works fine, it just seems that when webpack calls either the `after-emit` event or the `done` event, it is not actually done emitting or writing the files to the file system. My copy ends up copying either empty files or partially written files.

Here is the entire plugin:

```
'use strict';
var ncp = require('ncp').ncp;

function WebPackDeployAfterBuild(options) {
    var defaultOptions = {

    };

    this.options = Object.assign(defaultOptions, options);
}

WebPackDeployAfterBuild.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
    const options = this.options;

    compiler.plugin("done", (stats) => {
            console.log(Object.keys(stats.compilation.assets));
            console.log("\nExecuting Deploy on done...");
            ncp(options.from, options.to, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Err in ncp");
                }
                console.log(`Finished deploying ${options.from} to ${options.to}`);
            });
    });

    compiler.plugin("after-emit", (compilation, callback) => {
        console.log(Object.keys(compilation.assets));
        console.log("\nExecuting Deploy on after-emit...");
        ncp(options.from, options.to, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Err in ncp");
            }
            console.log(`Finished deploying ${options.from} to ${options.to}`);
            callback();
        });
    });
};

module.exports = WebPackDeployAfterBuild;
```

Here is the usage in my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
config.plugins.push(
        new WebPackDeployAfterBuild({
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, './myOutputPath'),
            to: 'Q:/'
        })
    )
```

I've included both the `done` and `after-emit` handlers, but in practice I've been commenting one out. I only need to run the event once, but both of these events are firing too soon. Is there another event I can use?

E: Forgot to mention, I am also running this on a webpack --watch task. I want to save a file, have webpack process it and immediately deploy it to my server while I develop. If there is a better dev workflow, I'm open to suggestions.

E2: Here's a log of what happens:

```
2ms optimize chunk assets
7ms optimize assets
 95% emit
[ 'scripts/app.bundle.js', 'scripts/vendor.bundle.js' ]

Executing Deploy After build...
11ms emit
Hash: a005eef9ae47a167f791
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 278ms
                Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
scripts/app.bundle.js  61.1 kB       0  [emitted]  scripts/app
    + 20 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
        + 3 hidden modules
Finished deploying C:\Users\redacted\Source\myprojectOutput to Q:/
```

You can see that the logging I do occurs before the `11ms emit` message, I would expect it to be after that...

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Those events still run before assets are written to the file system in webpack 2.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a `webpack --watch` run, consider using webpack-dev-middleware to perform your auto-recompile instead; you can use the `waitUntilValid` method to add a callback that will execute after all of the other logging occurs: [Documentation and simple example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#waituntilvalidcallback).