# Executing shell command after Webpack post build

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project and as you know when you deploy your app everything in your public directory should be copied over to your htdocs or public_html directory to hide your application's code.

I am using webpack to build my react code and everything else and each time I change my javascript webpack does what I want, it sees I make a change and then it builds it. 
However I want to add one additional command after it builds and that is to copy everything from the public directory into the correct directory in htdocs/public_html.

So far I read up on this question here [Run command after webpack build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312715/run-command-after-webpack-build)

It works and I can get the echo to work but I'm not sure why cp isn't working. Echo works but how do I know what shell commands I can use?
I tried 'cp' and even 'copy-item' which is powershell, but none are working.

This is my plugin so far, I figured I needed to change the directory to be safe
before copying anything over but again, nothing is working.

```
mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
  return {
    plugins: [
      new WebpackShellPlugin({
        onBuildStart: ['echo "Starting Build ..."'],
        onBuildEnd: ["cd 'E:\\xammp\\apps\\FactorioCalculator'",
          "cp '.\\public\\*' '..\\..\\htdocs\\FactorioCalculator\\' -f -r"]
      })
    ]
  };
});
```

Comment: What version or Laravel / Laravel mix are you using?

Comment: i suggest writing the commands in a seperate `.sh` file and calling that from the above events, since each `" "` is ran as a standalone command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use the `copyDirectory` mix method. Just put something like the following at the bottom of your `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
mix.copyDirectory('public', '../../htdocs/FactorioCalculator/')
```

You might have to change your path to `..\\..\\htdocs\\FactorioCalculator\\` as per the path in your question (I only have my mac with me so I'm unable to test on my other machine).

---

To answer you original question, if you want to execute a command each time webpack finishes building you can use the `mix.then()` which takes a closure.

Comment: @Richard Glad I could help!