# How can I configure Webpack and Vue-Loader to treat warnings as errors?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

**QUESTION**: How can I configure `Webpack` to treat warnings as errors when using `Vue-Loader`?

**BACKGROUND**: My Webpack configuration is using Vue-Loader to build an app that uses Vue single-file components. I'd like the build to fail and produce an error when warnings such as the below occur:

```
WARNING in ./{SOME_COMPONENT}.vue ({BOILERPLATE_PATHS}) 107:6-34
"export '{SOME_FUNCTION}' was not found in '../../{SOME_MODULE}'
```

The warning above surfaces when I'm trying to import a "named" export from a module that only contains a default export.

**I've reviewed the docs at the links below, but I don't see anything that would allow me to achieve my goal:**

- https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html
- https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/en/options.html

For non-watch builds, I suppose it would be possible to parse the build output for warnings using a regex and trigger an action that could fail a CI build, but I'd ideally like to be able to fail watch builds as well. Maybe there's a post-build Webpack hook or something? I'm open to suggestions.

---

**My current Vue-Loader/Webpack config is basically**:

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, './SomeFolder/')
    ],
    exclude: [
       path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/'),
       path.resolve(__dirname, './SomeFolder/Tests/')
    ],
},
```

Comment: This is looking promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312715/run-command-after-webpack-build

Comment: Could you replicate the problem in a GH repo or a [StackBlitz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-frqpha?file=index.js) ?